# Binary search not working for repetitive case of not a triangle

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

For "Not a triangle" [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NOTATRI/), I solved used binary search for finding the sum of two sides. For repetitions, I solved it using linear search thereafter. For repetitions, binary search can again be used and I have tested that too. I did not find any missing case. I have kept the second binary search in commented code below. However, when I submitted the code with second binary search, I was getting wrong answer while replacing the second binary search with linear search was accepted. Please point out what case is not covered when using the second binary search.

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        while(n != 0){
            int arr[] = new int[n];
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1; j < n - 1; j++) {
                    int sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
                    int insertionPoint = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, sum);
                    if(insertionPoint > 0){
                        /*int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, sum +1);
                        if (index > 0)
                            count += n - index;
                        else
                            count += n + index + 1;*/
                        for (int k = insertionPoint+1; k < n; k++) {
                            if(arr[insertionPoint] == arr[k]){
                                insertionPoint++;
                            }
                        }
                        count += n - insertionPoint - 1;
                    }else {
                        count += n + insertionPoint + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }
```